# Can't able to select an element inside a div loaded using jQuery Ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Working with a project, Loading a calender from a php file using ajax call. When i'm try to trigger an event written on the loaded table it seems not working.

Please help me.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'calender.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res){
        $("#calender").html(res);
    }
});

$("#prev").click(function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

PHP Code here.

```
*<?php
$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");

$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];

$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;

if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
    $prev_month = 12;
    $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>
<table width="300">
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left"><a id="prev" title="<?php echo $prev_month."|".$prev_year; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
<td width="50%" align="right"><a id="next" title="<?php echo $next_month."|".$next_year; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);" style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" id="calen">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align="center" bgcolor="#FFB102" style="color:#FFFFFF">S</th>
<th align="center" bgcolor="#FFB102" style="color:#FFFFFF">M</th>
<th align="center" bgcolor="#FFB102" style="color:#FFFFFF">T</th>
<th align="center" bgcolor="#FFB102" style="color:#FFFFFF">W</th>
<th align="center" bgcolor="#FFB102" style="color:#FFFFFF">T</th>
<th align="center" bgcolor="#FFB102" style="color:#FFFFFF">F</th>
<th align="center" bgcolor="#FFB102" style="color:#FFFFFF">S</th>
</tr>
<?php 
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
    if($i < $startday){
        echo "<td></td>";
    }else{
        $currentDay = date("d");
        $presentDay = $i-$startday+1;
        if($presentDay == $currentDay){
            echo "<td class='current' align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'><a title='".($i - $startday + 1)."' href='javascript:void(0);'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a></td>";
        }else if($presentDay < $currentDay){
            echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'><a title='".($i - $startday + 1)."' href='javascript:void(0);'>". ($i - $startday + 1) . "</a></td>";
        }
    }
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
?>*
```

What can be the issue ?

Comment: beacuse when you are binding that event, that element is not present in dom tree, it is dynamically inserted

Comment: Yes i understand that. is there any way to prevent it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are loading the element in dynamically you will need to use delegates instead of binding.

```
$(document).on('click', '#prev', function(){
    console.log(this);
});
```

Use the following code assuming '#calendar' exists in the dom at the time of execution of the following code. Bind the delegate event handler to the closest DOM element possible.

```
$("#calender").on('click', '#prev', function(){
    console.log(this);
});)
```

Comment: Can u elaborate ? how that thing exactly happend ?

Comment: `.on()` with the second parameter will cause it to bind a delegate handler onto the element you specify. In the general case you can use `$(document)` but more specificity is better. The element will then catch events that bubble up from elements lower in the DOM which includes elements that were not already in the DOM at the time you attached the handler.

Answer (score 2):

Put your event handler into your success callback of the ajax call should solve this problem. This is because the of the problem stated in the comments to your question: the DOM elements you're binding your handler to are not present when the handler is created. The other solution to bind the handler to the document using "on" is working, too.

EDIT: **As stated in the comments to my answer, be careful that you don't create duplicate event handlers, when this ajax call is called more than once.**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'calender.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res){
        $("#calender").html(res);
        $("#prev").click(function(){
            console.log(this);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this before. Here it can able to accept one click. I want to do it continuously when ever user clicks on my link.

Comment: Beware the issues that can be caused by binding events in an ajax callback however. Duplicate event handlers can be a pain to debug

Comment: Yeah, you're right, this is the reason why I'm more convinced of you're solution than my own. I will add this warning to my answer.